# Iteratin trought LINQ with index in collection

Tags: c#, linq

```
private void Right_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var ctx = new NORTHWNDEntities())
        {
            int txBoxId = int.Parse(Id.Text);


            var query = (from x in ctx.Employees where x.Employees1.Count >= txBoxId + 1 select x);
            List<Employee> emp = query.ToList();


            foreach (Employee c in emp)
            {
                Id.Text = c.EmployeeID.ToString();
                FirstName.Text = c.FirstName;
                LastName.Text = c.LastName;
                DateOfBirth.Text = c.BirthDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
            }
        }

    }
```

I want to go trought collection using index, any suggestion?

Comment: Where do you need your index, in the query or in the `foreach` loop? If it is the loop, why not use a `for` loop?

Comment: for (int index = 0; index < emp.Count(); index++)

Comment: I need to move trought collection using next and previous button, and fill texboxes with data, so i think ill need to use index in the query.

Answer (score 1):

`emp` is a `List`, you can simply iterate over every element in a normal `for` loop:

```
for(int index = 0; index < emp.Count; index++)
{
    var employee = emp[index];
    //...
}
```

Just seen your edit, you can access index in your query using method syntax instead of query syntax LINQ:

```
var query = ctx.Employees
    .Where((x, index) => x.Employees1.Count >= txBoxId + 1);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i get this exeption An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

Comment: The indexed overload of Where doesn't work where querying the database. In addition, if your'e not using the parameter `index` then it is useless.